# In Python, is an "and" statement or all() faster?

Tags: python

When testing if multiple conditions are True, are `and` statements or `all()` faster? For example:

```
if '1234'.isdigit() and '4567'.isdigit() and '7890'.isdigit(): 
    print "All are digits!"
```

or

```
if all(['1234'.isdigit(), '4567'.isdigit(), '7890'.isdigit()]): 
    print "All are digits!"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would propose that if nothing else, `all` looks better... why don't you set up a big loop and see what the results are?

Comment: More importantly, I'm willing to bet no real program you can possibly devise or even imagine will ever need to care about the speed of such a thing with only 3 values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`and`s are faster, there is no list creation and no function call.

```
In [10]: %timeit '1234'.isdigit() and '4567'.isdigit() and '7890'.isdigit()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 186 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit all(['1234'.isdigit(), '4567'.isdigit(), '7890'.isdigit()])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 323 ns per loop
```

`and`s wouldn't even unnecessarily evaluate things:

```
In [1]: def x():
   ...:     print 'call'
   ...:     return False
   ...:

In [2]: x() and x()
call
Out[2]: False

In [3]: all([x(), x()])
call
call
Out[3]: False
```

Comment: What's that percentage sign syntax?

Comment: Minor point: it tends to be faster to make a tuple than a list.  Seldom worth worrying about in real code but it can sometimes account for 20-25% of the time in tiny benchmarks like this.

Comment: @DSM -- This is definitely true in places where the tuples can be interned -- e.g. if they contain only literals.  I'm not sure how they compare in other cases.

Comment: @mgilson: well, now you've made me check. :^)  I find that using `all(('1234'.isdigit(), '4567'.isdigit(), '7890'.isdigit()))` is 20% faster than the same with a list, even though the components aren't literals.

Comment: @mgilson: If you need to optimize code that already takes under 500ns, it's pretty much worth trying everything just to see…

Comment: @DSM -- Cool.  Thanks for checking.  I only commented because I *know* that the case where it can be interned is faster (just from looking at the bytecode).  Did you by chance look at the bytecode from that one?

Comment: @mgilson: the two differ only in `BUILD_TUPLE` vs `BUILD_LIST`.

Comment: @DSM -- Yep.  I checked it out myself too.  Neat.

Answer (score 5):

The second one evaluates all of the conditions, puts those boolean values into a list and *then* checks to see if they're all true.

The first, on the other hand, just checks them all one-by-one and stops at the first false condition (if there is one). The first one is definitely faster, as Pavel's answer shows.

You could also use a generator, which lets `all` short-circuit:

```
all(str.isdigit(s) for s in your_strings)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the fastest way to deal with 3 static values, and the dozens of nanoseconds of difference actually matters in your code:

```
if True:
    print "All are digits!"
```

Or, even faster:

```
print "All are digits!"
```

In any case where the performance matters in the slightest, you will have a large and/or dynamic set of values, and you simply can't do that with `and`, except by creating an explicit `for` loop:

```
value = True
for s in strings:
    value = value and s.isdigit()
    if not value:
        break
if value:
    print "All are digits!"
```

And you can immediately see how the `and` isn't helping things at all:

```
for s in strings:
    if not s.isdigit():
        break
else:
    print "All are digits!"
```

But if you want to do things faster with `all`, you can use a generator expression (or a `map`/`imap` call) instead of a list comprehension, and it's just as fast, and readable, with a large, dynamic sequence as with a small, static one:

```
if all((x.isdigit() for x in ('1234', '4567', '7890')):
    print "All are digits!"

if all((x.isdigit() for x in strings):
    print "All are digits!"
```

If the sequence is very big, and it's possible that some of the values are false, this will be hugely faster than anything involving building a `list` of all of the True/False values.